# OWL Punning using the same resource as object of rdf:type and rdfs:subClassOf?

Tags: rdf, owl

Using [Punning](https://www.w3.org/2007/OWL/wiki/Punning), one can model the same RDF resource as both a class and an individual at the same time. However in the examples I looked at, a resource is never used as object of both `rdf:type` and `rdfs:subClassOf` for the same subject. Is that an acceptable way of modelling or would a paper describing that dataset be rejected to due horrible modelling practices? I do not want to use any OWL reasoning or inferencing, just SHACL validation, which this would enable.

### Example

```
:Animal a owl:Class.
:family a owl:ObjectProperty; rdfs:domain :Animal.
:order  a owl:ObjectProperty; rdfs:domain :Animal.

:Elefant rdfs:subClassOf :Animal;
         rdf:type        :Animal;
 :family    :Elephantidae;
 :order     :Proboscidea.
```

The reason I need both is that I want a subclass hierarchy, but I also have some properties that I want to attach to each one, and rdfs:domain only works with individuals, not classes.

### Alternative

Alternatively, I could model it in the following way but that feels much less elegant to me:

```
:Animal a owl:Class.
:AnimalSubClass a owl:Class.
:family a owl:ObjectProperty; rdfs:domain :AnimalSubclass.
:order  a owl:ObjectProperty; rdfs:domain :AnimalSubclass.

:Elefant rdfs:subClassOf :Animal;
         rdf:type        :AnimalSubClass;
 :family    :Elephantidae;
 :order     :Proboscidea.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably go with your first approach rather than the alternative. Particularly because punning does not have a substantial affect on reasoning in OWL 2. In OWL 1 it caused an ontology to be in the OWL Full profile rather than the OWL DL profile. For OWL 2 this is no longer the case. See [OWL 2 DL and OWL 2 Full](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-primer/#OWL_2_DL_and_OWL_2_Full).